# Proper communication

Tags: python, android, rest, websocket, communication

I'm wondering which communication method use in my app. There will be python server displaing data from website and from android app. That is easier part where I will use REST. But then I need communication back to android app from server and also from server to second android app. I thought about sockets. Is it proper way? Mayby REST isn't good choice also?

Give my some tips please. Thank you on advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions that are primarily opinion-based are explicitly _off topic_.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using `sockets` can be a suitable method for bidirectional communication between your Python server and Android apps.

But you can consider `the below list of communication methods for your app:

- `REST` for data retrieval.
- `WebSocket` for real-time bidirectional communication.
- Push Notifications for server-to-app updates.
- Long Polling with REST for simple real-time updates.
- `MQTT` for publish-subscribe communication.

To say, `WebSocket`  is often a good choice for real-time communication,